# Limit Database user priviliges

Tags: sql-server

I want to limit the user who access Database from Connection string to execute just Stored procedures , but no idea how to do that .

any tutorial ?

Comment: Every user access to DB based on Connection String. Describe more precisely - what do you wand, and what NOT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On a per-SP basis:

```
GRANT EXECUTE ON OBJECT::YourSchema.YourSP TO YourUser
```

However, you may want to group your SPs into one or more schemas, and your users into one or more roles, and grant permissions that way instead. For example:

```
GRANT EXECUTE ON SCHEMA:YourSchema TO YourRoleOrUser
```

If your users already exist, you may also need to revoke old permissions before granting new ones.